# How to Communicate a Fragment with PhoneStateListener

Tags: java, android, phone-state-listener

I have the following 2 classes the first it's a tab for Tabbed activity and the second it used to take LTE connection data from the phone. I need to print the values into the fragment. Before this, the code of first class was into an Activity but needed to move into `extends Fragment`.

```
public class Tab1Values extends Fragment {
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    int value=0,dbm=0;
    String ptype="",ntype="";
    public Tab1Values() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info);
        tv2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info2);
        tv3=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info3);
        TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        ->tm.listen(new Tab1Signal2(this.getActivity()), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        String opname="\nOperator ID:"+" "+tm.getNetworkOperator();
        opname=opname+"\nOperator Name:"+" "+tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
        int phoneType=tm.getPhoneType(),networkType=tm.getNetworkType();

        return v;
    }
}
```

**SecondClass**

```
public class Tab1Signal2 extends PhoneStateListener {
    Context mcontext;
    int LteSignalStrength=0,LteRsrp=0,LteRsrq=0,LteRssnr=0,LteCqi=0;
    int value1=0,value2=0,CdmaDbm=0,CdmaEcio=0,EvdoDbm=0,EvdoEcio=0,EvdoSnr=0;
    //int cid=0,lac=0,psc=0,statid=0,netid=0,sysid=0,lat=0,lon=0;
    String error,ss,val1,ccloc;
    private Tab1Values main;

    public Tab1Signal2(Context context){
        mcontext=context;
        ->main=(Tab1Values) mcontext;
    }
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength){
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
            value1=signalStrength.getGsmBitErrorRate();
            value2=signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
        }else if (signalStrength.getCdmaDbm() > 0) {
            CdmaDbm=signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
            CdmaEcio=signalStrength.getCdmaEcio();
        } else {
            EvdoDbm=signalStrength.getEvdoDbm();
            EvdoEcio=signalStrength.getEvdoEcio();
            EvdoSnr=signalStrength.getEvdoSnr();
        }
        try {
            Method[] methods = android.telephony.SignalStrength.class
                    .getMethods();
            for (Method mthd : methods) {
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteSignalStrength")){
                    //val1=mthd.getName() ;
                    LteSignalStrength=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                    //main.test(val2);
                }
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRsrp")){
                    LteRsrp=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                }
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRsrq")){
                    LteRsrq=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                }
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRssnr")){
                    LteRssnr=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                }
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteCqi")){
                    LteCqi=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                }
                main.test(LteSignalStrength,LteRsrp,LteRsrq,LteRssnr,LteCqi);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have put an arrow at the lines that I think it is the mistake.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EventBus` to pass the needed data

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Event to be sent, you can add fields that you want to pass:

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

Add function for eventBus listening:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Register event in fragment (and unregister) for example:

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

And post event:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```